# Normal Bayes Classifer Negative Samples

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, classification, bayesian

I am new to this classification and I am confused about negative sample training. Do we really need negative samples while training the Bayesian Classifer?

I am trying to identify if the object on the road is a car, truck or an animal.

I want to train several samples of each image, but I am confused as to whether I need negative samples as well. What is a negative sample and what could be some possible negative samples in my system?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to decide whether you are going to do recognition. Recognition and detection are different processes.

- are you going to have 3 systems detecting cars, trucks and animals respectively
- or are you going to have 1 system detecting all of these, but also classifying somehow with a recognition step.

Second, "animal" detection is a hard process, where "cat" detection is easier. Please narrow down your range and make the positives similar. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444433/advice-to-consider-when-training-a-robust-cascade-classifier/17446714#17446714) for a similar problem.

Third, as you already noticed, you actually need more negatives than positives for a proper training.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have few confusion which i want to clarify. before that, the animal is only cows so that makes my work easy. My first confusion is what actual cant be my negative samples? as of now i am using trees, planes, boats,etc haha sounds foolish i guess but i thought that such things will not be on the road that is my reason. Question 2) All these negative sample if i am correct with it,than  has have same label or different labels. I assign them label of -1, that is same since i thought its all one class that is negative. Please help me out with this.